# R truncates numbers from Excel

Tags: r, excel

I have a large dataset as a .csv file with one important column being a 14 digit number. When opening it in R or Excel, the number becomes truncated i.e. 83990969388422 becomes 8.4^13. I tried saving the file as an Excel worksheet file where the numbers are correctly displayed. However, as soon as I import it to R, the numbers become truncated.

How do I avoid this truncation in R?

Comment: The number is not changed at all. This is just a display format.

Answer (score 2):

To set the use of scientific notation in your entire R session, you can use the scipen option. From the documentation (?options)

`options(scipen=999)`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, you can use `options(scipen = 999)`. However, this always prevents R from using scientific notation. So this is mostly usefull if you never want the scientific notation. If it is just specific variables you don't want in scientific notation, you could also mutate the variable using `format(., scientific = FALSE)` to turn off the scientific notation for that specific variable.